# Android Studio me genera 2 aplicaciones

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo mi proyecto en Android Studio y al generar al apk esta todo correcto.

El tema viene cuando la instalo , la instalación me genera 2 aplicaciones de mi proyecto: una que va al LOGIN la correcta  y otra que va a otra ventana de mi proyecto

No encuentro dónde se especifíca ésto.

Mi manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


<service android:name=".MiFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>


<service
    android:name=".MiFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>



<application
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/mm_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".mibancodatalledos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TransferenciasBanco"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".mibancoDetalle"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CashOutCorresponsalQRstep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".miBanco"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SendMoneyValidacion"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep1AgregarBilletera"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CorresponsalCASHOUT_SV"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CashOutCorresponsalActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ComprasManual"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Online"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Online_Step2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CorresponsalCASHINCV"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CorresponsalCASHIN_SV"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Online_Step3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".HomeActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".RecoverPasswordStep1Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RecoverPasswordStep2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RecoverPasswordStep3Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>




    <activity
        android:name=".AtmCorresponsalActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MovementsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MovementsDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MovementsActivity" />
    </activity>


    <!--REGISTRATION-->
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".RegistrationActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".RegistrationActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--LINK ACCOUNT SELECTION-->
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountSelectionActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountSelectionActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountSelectionActivityStep1" />
    </activity>

    <!--LINK ACCOUNT CREDIT CARD-->
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountCreditCardActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountSelectionActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountCreditCardActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountCreditCardActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountCreditCardActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountCreditCardActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--LINK ACCOUNT BANK ACCOUNT-->
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountBankAccountActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountSelectionActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountBankAccountActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountBankAccountActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LinkAccountBankAccountActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LinkAccountBankAccountActivityStep2" />
    </activity>


    <!--PRE APPROVED ACCOUNT SELECTION-->
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountSelectionActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountSelectionActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountSelectionActivityStep1" />
    </activity>

    <!--PRE APPROVED ACCOUNT CREDIT CARD-->
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountWalletActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountSelectionActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountWalletActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountWalletActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountWalletActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountWalletActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--PRE APPROVED ACCOUNT BANK ACCOUNT-->
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountBankAccountActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountSelectionActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountBankAccountActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountBankAccountActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PreApprovedAccountBankAccountActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PreApprovedAccountBankAccountActivityStep2" />
    </activity>



    <!--CASH OUT ATM-->
    <activity
        android:name=".CashOutAtmActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".AtmCorresponsalActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Compras"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashOutAtmActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashOutAtmActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashOutAtmActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashOutAtmActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--CASH OUT CORRESPONSAL-->

    <activity
        android:name=".CashOutCorresponsalActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashOutCorresponsalActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashOutCorresponsalActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashOutCorresponsalActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--CASH IN-->
    <activity
        android:name=".CashInActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinQRActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinQRActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinQRActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinQRActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinQRActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinQRActivityStep4"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinQRActivityStep3" />
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".CashinManualActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashInActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinManualActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinManualActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinManualActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinManualActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CashinManualActivityStep4"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CashinManualActivityStep3" />
    </activity>

    <!--CHANGE PASSWORD-->
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePasswordStep1Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePasswordStep2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ChangePasswordStep1Activity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePasswordStep3Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ChangePasswordStep2Activity" />
    </activity>

    <!--CHANGE EMAIL-->
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangeEmailStep1Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangeEmailStep2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ChangeEmailStep1Activity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangeEmailStep3Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ChangeEmailStep2Activity" />
    </activity>

    <!--CONFIGURATION-->
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfigurationActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfigurationActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ConfigurationActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfigurationActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ConfigurationActivityStep2" />
    </activity>


    <!--TRANSFERENCIA-->
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep1" />
    </activity>


    <!--TRANSFERENCIA MISMO BANCO, CUENTAS PROPIAS-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".TransferOwnAccountActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferOwnAccountActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferOwnAccountActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferOwnAccountActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferOwnAccountActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--TRANSFERENCIA MISMO BANCO, CUENTAS TERCEROS-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".TransferThirdAccountActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferThirdAccountActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferThirdAccountActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferThirdAccountActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferThirdAccountActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--TRANSFERENCIA DISTINTO BANCO-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".TransferDistinctBankActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferDistinctBankActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferDistinctBankActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferDistinctBankActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferDistinctBankActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--TRANSFERENCIA CUENTA BANCO BILLETERA-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".TransferWalletToBankAccountActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep3" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferWalletToBankAccountActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferWalletToBankAccountActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferWalletToBankAccountActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferWalletToBankAccountActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <!--TRANSFERENCIA BILLETERA CUENTA BANCO-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".TransferBankAccountToWalletActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferActivityStep3" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferBankAccountToWalletActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferBankAccountToWalletActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TransferBankAccountToWalletActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".TransferBankAccountToWalletActivityStep2" />
    </activity>


    <!--ENVIAR DINERO-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SendMoneyActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SendMoneyActivityStep2" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep4"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SendMoneyActivityStep3" />
    </activity>

    <!--PAGAR SERVICIO-->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".ServicePayActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PayActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ServicePayActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ServicePayActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ServicePayActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ServicePayActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:name=".PurchaseActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PayActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PurchaseActivityStep2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PurchaseActivityStep1" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PurchaseActivityStep3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PurchaseActivityStep2" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PayActivityStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es debido a que en tu manifest tienes definido 2 actividades como con el intent-filter `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` lo que le indica al sistema que instale la aplicacion 2 veces.

Solo debe de haber una sola actividad con los atributos:

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Y como publicas, tienes 2:

```
 <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SendMoneyActivityStep1AgregarBilletera"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```